# How to pass the value of the variable in python

Tags: python, date

I have to the pass the date value as the variable. here is my code to calcuate current mnth and prev. mnth

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()

Curr_Mnth=datetime.date(day=1,month=today.month,year=today.year)
Prev_Mnth=Curr_Mnth - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

c=str(Curr_Mnth.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
p=str (Curr_Mnth.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
```

I  want the the value fo the c and p to be passed

```
ENDPOINT_site_totals = '/sites/site_totals?DateStamp=gte:"c":+AND+lt:"p"'
```

Can anyone help me in this .

Answer (score 0):

```
ENDPOINT_site_totals = '/sites/site_totals?DateStamp=gte:"{0}":+AND+lt:"{1}"'.format(c, p)
```